# echo statements in a shell script run by cron

Tags: shell, unix

I am using echo statements in a shell script. The shell script will be run by a cronjob.Will the output of those echo statements get automatically logged somewhere ?. If yes,where ?

Thank You

Comment: Yes you can just redirect them using the redirection operator ('>') and have it in a temporary dump file for your own convenience.

Comment: Hi, I met your issue now, how did you do?

Answer (score 3):

Usually crond will email output to the user.  You are better off doing this (example crontab entry)

```
* * * * * /path/to/my/script.sh 2&>1 > /tmp/mylogfile.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either check syslogs or redirect the output of your script to a file.